# with splice() can we delete specific element from an array containing many json objects and withoutusing findIndex() method?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Whenever I check the delete operation in postman than it always deletes the last element of the array. I want a particular element to be deleted.if without using findIndex() method some changes being done in this code only so that it can also make working with splice() only.basically the users[] array is there in which details of each user are stores in json format like

```
user = {
           username: req.body.username,
           password: req.body.password
       }
```

so can we apply map function on this code with splice and after serching in array remove that user.it wil be more heplful for me if splice()is used in same code and not findIndex().

Code:

```
    app.post('/delete-user', (req, res)=> {
    users.splice(users.indexOf({ username: req.body.username, password:req.body.password}, 1))

    res.send(users)
})
```

Comment: `users.splice(users.indexOf({ username: req.body.username, password:req.body.password}, 1))` will remove the particular username information from the array.

Comment: No,it deletes last element only from array irrespective of what we are provididng

Comment: `users.indexOf({ username: req.body.username, password:req.body.password}` returns the index of the element in the `users` array. `1` in the `splice` argument basically tells to perform a deletion at the index return by your `indexOf` method. So hence, the first argument of the `splice` function will delete the element from the array, provided that the element is found in the array, otherwise it will return -1.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `filter` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
const newUsers = users.filter((user) => {
  return user.id !== id // Get a new array of users excluding the user with the sepcified ID
})

res.send(newUsers)
```